# Python flask cannot open an xml file

Tags: python, xml, flask

I try to implement a server-side multilanguage service on my website. This is the structure on the folders:

```
data
--locale
static
--css
--images
--js
templates
--index.html
--page1.html
...
main.py
```

I use Crowdin to translate the website and the output files are in XML. The locale folder contains one folder for each language with one xml file for every page.

I store on Cookies the language and here is my python code:

```
from flask import request
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

def languages(page):
    langcode = request.cookies.get("Language")
    xml = "/data/locale/%s/%s.xml" % (langcode, page)

    dom = parseString(xml)
    ................
    .............
```

Which I call in every page, like `languages("index")`

This is an example of the exported xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Generated by crowdin.com-->
<!--
This is a description of my page
-->
<resources>
  <string name="name1">value 1</string>
  <string name="name2">value 2</string>
  <string name="name3">value 3</string>
</resources>
```

However, I have the following error `ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0`

I googled it. I ended up to other stackoverflow questions, but most of them says about encoding problems and I cannot find any in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `parse()` if you want to parse a file. `parseString()` will parse a string, the file name in your case.

```
from flask import request
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

def languages(page):
    langcode = request.cookies.get("Language")
    xml = "/data/locale/%s/%s.xml" % (langcode, page)

    dom = parse(xml)
```

Comment: That was easy :) Thank you